# is there a way to set password for each db in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-grant, user-data

Is there a any way to set password for each database in MySQL server . if there , give some suggestions.

Comment: passwd for db or passwd for user ?

Comment: you have the answer from Jimp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot set passwords on MySQL databases. You can set passwords for users with privileges granted per database, table, etc.

[CREATE USER Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-user.html)

```
CREATE USER 'jeffrey'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
```

[GRANT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html)

```
GRANT ALL ON db1.* TO 'jeffrey'@'localhost';
GRANT SELECT ON db2.invoice TO 'jeffrey'@'localhost';
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'jeffrey'@'localhost' WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 90;
```

That should help get you started.